# Annoying transition in beamer

Tags: beamer, transition

I am experience an annoying trouble in `beamer`:

When I open the generated PDF in presentation mode there is an annoying transition between slides that last half a second and makes the slides look like not on focus.

Which command should I use to remove this effect? I do not want any form of transition from a slide to another.

Comment: That sound like a problem of your pdf-viewer. But if you think, that it's related to the LaTeX Code you should make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: A small example is hard to do, because I have hardcoded many parts of the presentation. Perhaps, what could help, is to know that I am using metropolis as main theme. So my question could be restated as "Is there a way to tell beamer to remove any transition, whatever is the theme used"?

Comment: You could try different PDF-viewers, that are caching the slides before, to see if the problem appears there too. What viewer did you use?

Comment: Are you using mac?

Comment: If yes, maybe related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431423/os-x-blurry-beamer-presentations-on-sierra-high-sierra

Comment: yes! I am on macOS

Comment: @DanCat Than I'm afraid this a bug of mac, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431696/36296 for alternative presentation programs